# certain link for like?

Tags: facebook-like, customization

is there a specific link that I can use for "Liking" something? I'm looking to make a rating system that when someones votes something as 5 stars, it automatically "Likes" the image or whatever. I know there is www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?, but when I use that in my JavaScript, it automatically forwards them to a page with a like button only on it...

FYI, I'm not hiding the like button, it will be known by users...

I also tried .trigger('click'); but that doesn't work with the like button!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think Facebook has done and will always do its best to make sure such a URL will be very very hard to construct. Think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have stumbled across some road-blocks that Facebook implemented to prevent abuse of their like button.  You will have to play by their rules to play in their sandbox they built.  So use the social plugin: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: that's what I was thinking... unfortunately

Comment: This also allows them to load their javascript on websites all over the net so they can gather all sorts of their own analytics.